# Why does the Ethereum blockchain need a consensus network?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

Why does Ethereum blockchain need computers to agree on blocks?  If by means of cryptography, only the private key holder can generate the appropriate hash for a certain transaction, why not let a single miner just include the transaction in the block.  Why the need for multiple computers to validate the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Giving this a shot but there are probably better answers.

Having more than one miner has advantages of decentralization and no single-point-of-failure. If a miner has an issue, other miners should be able to continue to process transactions. Decentralization also improves censorship resistance: a single miner would be able to censor transactions as they wish.

Multiple computers need to validate the transaction so that the miner cannot include an invalid transaction. Otherwise a miner could create invalid state transitions, like increasing the money they have.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches the "why" of Distributed Ledgers vs. Distributed Databases.
You fundamentaly use a DL because you operate a Distributed Database in an adversarial environment, without a central coordinator. Consensus is not only for Validation of Transactions but for example also about consensus obout the order of Transactions which manipulate the state of the DL.

[Rauchs et al.](https://doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.3040224) has a nice Definition of what a DLT is/does:

> A DLT system is a system of electronic records that enables a network
> of independent participants to establish a consensus around the
> authoritative ordering of cryptographically-validated (‘signed’)
> transactions. These records are made persistent by replicating the
> data across multiple nodes and tamper-evident by linking them by
> cryptographic hashes. The shared result of the
> reconciliation/consensus process (the ledger) serves as the
> authoritative version for these records.

And [Richard Brown](https://gendal.me/2016/11/08/on-distributed-databases-and-distributed-ledgers/) has a nice Article (where he mostly talks about Corda) where he shows the difference between Distributed Databases and Distributed Ledgers.
[image]